# Virtualbox stopped working PXE-E51, No DHCP or Proxy DHCP

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

The virtualbox suddenly keeps losing connectivity. Error message: Client Mac Addr.... PXE-E51, No DHCP or Proxy DHCP. PXE-MOF: Existing Intel PXE ROM. Fatal: Could not read from boot medium.

I use Bridged Adapter.

Has anyone seen this problem before? How to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a PXE server?  It appears that you don't have an OS installed and there's no CD/DVD/ISO to boot from and also no network server to boot off of PXE from.

Comment: No, I don't have a PXE server. Everytime  when it loses the connection it loses the "optical drive" & the iso that I pointed it to in the "Storage" section of Settings. I don't understand how this happens.

Comment: Your ISO is on a network share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has miraculously fixed itself. Well, I did a complete reinstall, it's working fine now.